# How come I can't use `\` to continue a line in crontab?

Tags: cron, openbsd

The [acme-client(1) man page](https://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-6.7/acme-client) suggests the following cron entry:

```
~   *   *   *   *   acme-client example.com && \
    rcctl reload httpd
```

When I add to `crontab` the edit is not saved when I use that syntax:

```
crontab: installing new crontab
"/tmp/crontab.nOryzjBTlv":22: bad minute
crontab: errors in crontab file, unable to install
Do you want to retry the same edit?
```

But it saves fine if I just make it a single line:

```
~   *   *   *   *   acme-client example.com && \ rcctl reload httpd
```

Why doesn't `\` allow continuing a line to the next one?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> There is no way to split a single command line onto multiple lines, like the shell's trailing "\"

You'll find the above statement in the following paragraph if you do `man 5 crontab`. Please note below is from Ubuntu 20.04LTS.

> The ``sixth'' field (the rest of the line) specifies the command to be run.  The entire command portion of the line, up to a newline or % character, will be executed by /bin/sh or by the shell speci‐
> fied  in  the SHELL variable of the crontab file.  Percent-signs (%) in the command, unless escaped with backslash (\), will be changed into newline characters, and all data after the first % will be
> sent to the command as standard input.  There is no way to split a single command line onto multiple lines, like the shell's trailing "\"

From https://man.openbsd.org/crontab.5
It says the **rest of the line** is the command field, it does not say how a command span multiple lines. You should not assume that the crontab has the same syntax as the shell script.

> The command field (**the rest of the line**) is the command to be run. The entire command portion of the line, up to a newline or % character, will be executed by /bin/sh or by the shell specified in the SHELL variable of the crontab. Percent signs (‘%’) in the command, unless escaped with a backslash (‘\’), will be changed into newline characters, and all data after the first ‘%’ will be sent to the command as standard input.

Comment: I tend to feel that any crontab command that is not an easy one-liner deserves a proper separate script anyway.

Comment: The last line of that paragraph does not appear in the OpenBSD [crontab(5) man page](https://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-6.7/crontab.5).

Comment: @paul, I updated the answer. I think the acme-client man page is wrong.